# Can't get the thread to sleep after displaying my grid

Tags: java, eclipse, events, javafx

I have a grid Pane which I want to make visible. I want to then pause the program for 2 seconds and make the grid invisible again. For some reason the grid becomes visible after the thread.sleep that I use in my program.

This all happens inside a button click event.

I tried moving around the thread.sleep, putting them in a new method and using multiple sleep but nothing worked.

```java
gameGrid.setVisible(true) 
gameGrid.setVisible(false)
```

Button event:

```java
public void handleButtonGo(ActionEvent Event) throws IOException {    //On go button press

        boolean validation = true;
        try {

            gameGrid.setVisible(true);
            placeShips();        

        }catch (Exception e){

            labelwarning.setText(e.getMessage());   //on error the program will stop trying to place ships and refresh any ships placed so far.
            validation = false;
            //gameGrid.getChildren().clear();
            //BoardSetup();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            gameGrid.setVisible(false);

        }
}
```

The grid is displayed for a millisecond after the thread.sleep.

Comment: Look into JavaFX Animation Class. A lot of helpful stuff. More specifically PauseTransition.

Comment: Learn about `TimeLine` and `PauseTransition`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task. In the `PauseTransition` example, you don't need `wait.playFromStart();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).

```
public void handleButtonGo(ActionEvent Event) throws IOException {    //On go button press

        boolean validation = true;
        try {

            gameGrid.setVisible(true);
            placeShips();        

        }catch (Exception e){

            labelwarning.setText(e.getMessage());   //on error the program will stop trying to place ships and refresh any ships placed so far.
            validation = false;
            //gameGrid.getChildren().clear();
            //BoardSetup();
            PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
            wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {
                /*YOUR METHOD*/      
                gameGrid.setVisible(false);
            });
            wait.play();        

        }
}
```